# How to iterate through a Rails model's nested attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a collection of models: Users, Cvs, Skills, Educations, & Experiences.

```
# models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :cv
  has_many :skills, through: :cv, inverse_of: :user
  has_many :educations, through: :cv, inverse_of: :user
  has_many :experiences, through: :cv, inverse_of: :user
  ...
end

# models/cv.rb
class Cv < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :skills
  has_many :educations
  has_many :experiences
  ...
end

# models/skill.rb
class Skill < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :cv
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :skill
end

# models/education.rb
class Education < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :cv
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :education
end

# models/experience.rb
class Experience < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :cv
  belongs_to :user, inverse_of: :experience
end
```

So, basically, a `user` has 1 `cv` and many `skills`, `educations`, and `experiences` that are nested in that `cv`

A Cv has many attributes other than the nested `skills`, `educations`, and `experiences`.

How can I iterate through all of the attributes in a Cv, including the nested ones? I tried this:

```
@user = User.new

@user.build_cv
@user.cv.educations.build
@user.cv.experiences.build
@user.cv.skills.build

@user.cv.attributes.each_pair do |attr, value|
  puts "#{attr}: #{value}"
end
```

But this just lists the attributes that are directly in the Cv model and not the attributes for the Cv's `education`, `skill`, and `experience`. What I eventually need to do is iterate through the Cv attributes and it's nested attributes searching for blank values in order to make sure a Cv has been completed. I could do that with a simple `.blank?` on each attribute if I could just figure out how to iterate through them all.

So far, this is the most concise way I came up with to do it, I was just hoping that there was a built-in helper method for something like this:

```
def is_complete?
  user = current_user
  user.cv.attributes.each do |attr|
    return false if attr.blank?
  end
  user.cv.skills.each do |skill|
    skill.attributes.each do |sa|
      return false if sa.blank?
    end
  end
  user.cv.educations.each do |edu|
    edu.attributes.each do |ea|
      return false if ea.blank?
    end
  end
  user.cv.experiences.each do |exp|
    exp.attributes.each do |exa|
      return false if edu.blank?
    end
  end
  true
end
```

Comment: Your don’t need the belongs to user on Skills, Experiences and Educations. You have already the user through the cv. skill.cv.user, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reflect_on_all_associations`

```
Cv.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many).map(&:name).each do |attr|
  if @user.cv.send(attr).blank?
    # do something
  end
end
```

If you want to check individual attribute elements...

```
Cv.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many).map(&:name).each do |attr|
  @user.cv.send(attr).each do |item|
    if item.blank?
      # do something
    end
  end
end
```

or if you're looking at checking each attribute of each item...

If you want to check individual attribute elements...

```
Cv.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many).map(&:name).each do |attr|
  @user.cv.send(attr).each do |item|
    item.attributes.each_pair do |subattr, value|
      puts "#{item.class}.#{subattr}: #{value}"
    end
  end
end
```

But a more natural way to do this would be to put validations on the association models.

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for, I am just testing before I mark it as answered. I have validations but only if each attribute has a value. I want the user to have the option to leave an attribute blank, but, I don't want to consider a CV complete until all attributes have values. This way if they try to apply for a position but have not completed their CV, they can be redirected back to the incomplete forms. If they only fill out part of a form, however, I want them to be able to save it so they don't have to fill it all out again when they return.

Comment: Ah, makes sense.  Attributes missing means the CV can be pending, but not "live"? There are finite state machine gems that you may want to look at someday, where you can specify what validations must pass for what state the CV is in. But carry on! :) Looks good.